# Easiest strat to add a Subscribe module to a Mezzanine blog

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have a Mezzanine blog and I would like to add a little form to every page so users can type their email addresses and click 'subscribe' so, from that moment, an email will be sent to announce any new post to the blog.

I don't see that built in or any existing module for that purpose... Should I program that from scratch? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no answers, I will try to offer my best guess as to the easiest strategy in this situation. I don't know of any built-in functions in Mezzanine that perform this specific function, so here's how I would approach it:

1. `python manage.py startapp subscriber`
2. Build out basic model - `email = models.EmailField(unique=True)`, etc.
3. Create basic `admin.py`
4. Update `settings.py` -> `INSTALLED_APPS` and `ADMIN_MENU_ORDER`

   ```
   ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
       (_("Web Content"), ((_("Pages"), "pages.Page"),
           (_("Subscribers"), "subscriber.Subscriber"),
   ```
5. Create a `forms.py` - something like this:

   ```
   class SubscriberForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Subscriber
           fields = ['email']
   ```
6. Setup a `views.py` for GET/POST of above form
7. Reconfigure `urls.py` to redirect to the new view function
8. Then, perhaps the only interesting part of my response, I would copy the Mezzanine Blog app directory into the project directory, and create a `signals.py`. Maybe add something like this:

   ```
   @receiver(pre_save, sender=BlogPost, dispatch_uid="save_blogpost")
   def save_blogpost(sender, instance, **kwargs):
       """ Every time a new blog post is created, notify all subscribers."""
       if instance.published:
           subs = Subscriber.objects.all()
           for sub in subs:
               email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                   subject="New Blog Post!",
                   body="A new blog post has been added!",
                   from_email="example@email.com",
                   to=[sub.email]
               )
               email.attach_alternative(self.body, "text/html")
               email.send()
   ```
9. Update `app.py` in the blog app directory to contain this under the Config class:

   ```
   def ready(self):
       import blog.signals  # noqa
   ```

If you've got Django configured to send mail through an external SMTP mail server, that's easier. If not, you'll likely want to [setup Postfix](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) with [OpenDKIM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy) and configure [SPF](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/create-an-spf-txt-record/) to reduce probability the outgoing mail ends up in spam.

(Also, you'll obviously need to handle situations where an admin changes a draft post to a published post, etc.)

Not sure if this helps, but hopefully!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't have enough time to do it by myself, so I finally moved my blog idea into WordPress (I am ashamed, I know). I love python, but I think Mezzanine still has a long way to go (it should be A LOT easier to include it in an existing project, and widgets like `subscribe`, IMO, are mandatory nowadays in a blog. I mark your answer as the correct one since I agree it looks like the less bad option.

Comment: Thanks kindly! I couldn't agree more. I'm finally getting comfortable after a few hundred hours in Mezzanine, but the short-comings are still deeply apparent. On my next project, I'm moving over to Wagtail - I think it's the best option for Python web development at the moment.